# How can I achieve a parallax moving background with CSS and JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I want to achieve something like this: http://levenopmars.natgeotv.com/nl/

As you can see, the stars background slighting moves as you scroll down while the planet gets smaller and moves up.

For the question's sake, I will be using the same background and planet images as seen on the website above, but of course I won't be using those on my project.

I've been searching for days on google to learn how to do cool parallax effects but the resources are scarce and everyone is pointing out that [ScrollMagic JS](http://scrollmagic.io) is the way to go, but their documentation is minimal at best and doesn't explain much and the tutorials are lacking.

I don't mind doing this with jQuery only but I would prefer to learn to how to do this with ScrollMagic for the sake of consistency.

I've set up a jsfiddle with a simple bootstrap container and the stars background but I am unable to place the planet's image where it needs to be on the top center of the container. And I have no idea where to begin to do the parallax effect.

Stars Background: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvxCo.jpg

Planet's Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5cOQ.png

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/73p0336p/18/

HTML

```
<section id="third-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 class="text-left">The Launch</h1>
        <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla diam quis turpis eleifend, ac molestie diam consectetur. In at augue tellus. Pellentesque efficitur efficitur nisl, suscipit blandit mauris. Quisque consectetur tincidunt suscipit. Nullam fermentum dictum quam vel volutpat. Phasellus eleifend molestie neque id varius. Aenean convallis ornare nisi vitae blandit. Phasellus imperdiet, diam vel congue blandit, quam felis vehicula tellus, eget lacinia dui quam vel metus. Proin eleifend volutpat magna et convallis. Nam pharetra, orci eu aliquet efficitur, turpis leo consequat purus, sed fringilla metus arcu ac elit.</p>
          <p class="text-left">ALorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla diam quis turpis eleifend, ac molestie diam consectetur. In at augue tellus. Pellentesque efficitur efficitur nisl, suscipit blandit mauris. Quisque consectetur tincidunt suscipit. Nullam fermentum dictum quam vel volutpat. Phasellus eleifend molestie neque id varius. Aenean convallis ornare nisi vitae blandit. Phasellus imperdiet, diam vel congue blandit, quam felis vehicula tellus, eget lacinia dui quam vel metus. Proin eleifend volutpat magna et convallis. Nam pharetra, orci eu aliquet efficitur, turpis leo consequat purus, sed fringilla metus arcu ac elit.</p>
          <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla diam quis turpis eleifend, ac molestie diam consectetur. In at augue tellus. Pellentesque efficitur efficitur nisl, suscipit blandit mauris. Quisque consectetur tincidunt suscipit. Nullam fermentum dictum quam vel volutpat. Phasellus eleifend molestie neque id varius. Aenean convallis ornare nisi vitae blandit. Phasellus imperdiet, diam vel congue blandit, quam felis vehicula tellus, eget lacinia dui quam vel metus. Proin eleifend volutpat magna et convallis. Nam pharetra, orci eu aliquet efficitur, turpis leo consequat purus, sed fringilla metus arcu ac elit.</p>
          <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla diam quis turpis eleifend, ac molestie diam consectetur. In at augue tellus. Pellentesque efficitur efficitur nisl, suscipit blandit mauris. Quisque consectetur tincidunt suscipit. Nullam fermentum dictum quam vel volutpat. Phasellus eleifend molestie neque id varius. Aenean convallis ornare nisi vitae blandit. Phasellus imperdiet, diam vel congue blandit, quam felis vehicula tellus, eget lacinia dui quam vel metus. Proin eleifend volutpat magna et convallis. Nam pharetra, orci eu aliquet efficitur, turpis leo consequat purus, sed fringilla metus arcu ac elit.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #191617;
}
section {
    padding: 130px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
section::before,
section::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
}

#third-section {
    height: auto;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 3rem;
    color: #dcdcdc;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvxCo.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
#third-section h1 {
    font-size: 72px;
    color: #dcdcdc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in CSS:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

That should help.

Answer (score 0):

Use scrollspy.js and/or parallax.js for a clean effect (you can also tryna use pure CSS as other answers recommend you to)

PS: for responsive sake I do not recommend px or em for sizing